# Area of a parallelogram formed by 2 vectors

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, determinant, area

My question is to prove that the area of the parallelogram formed by 2 vectors starting at the origin and ending at $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is
$$\text{abs}\left(\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1\\x_2&y_2\end{vmatrix}\right).\tag1$$

What I know is that the area equals
$$\left|\sin\left(\arctan\frac{y_1}{x_1}-\arctan\frac{y_2}{x_2}\right)\right|\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}.\tag2$$
How to go from (2) to (1)? There must be an algebraic way, because, when I entered (2), without the absolute value sign around sine, to Wolfram Alpha, it gave me (1). Computers don’t reason via the geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be your two $\arctan.$ Then,
$$\begin{align}(2)&=|\sin(\alpha-\beta)||x_1|\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}|x_2|\sqrt{1+\tan^2\beta}\\
&=|x_1x_2|\left|\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\beta\cos\alpha}{\cos\alpha\cos\beta}\right|\\
&=|x_1x_2\tan\alpha-x_1x_2\tan\beta|\\
&=(1).\end{align}$$

Comment: Why $\sin|\theta|=|\sin\theta|$? For example, $\sin\left|\frac{3\pi}2\right|=-1\ne1=\left|\sin\frac{3\pi}2\right|$. But I agree that $|\sin\theta|$ is more correct than $\sin|\theta|$. Or are they equally correct provided $|\theta|\le\pi$?

Comment: You are right, I wanted to correct your formula but it was useless, both are equally correct as you said since $|\alpha-\beta|\le\pi.$ Thank you, I shall edit my answer.